# Newbie algorithm design

Tags: python, algorithm, logic

I'm new to algorithm design. I have a list of about 8128 integers. I need to create an algorithm that will create 128 different combinations of unique numbers.

The first number, 1, is'nt used by any combination. The first 6 number sequences begin as follows:

1. 2,4,7,11,16,22
2. 3,6,10,15,21
3. 5,9,14,20
4. 8,13,19
5. 12,18
6. 17

I notice that the interval between numbers increases by 1 between each sequence. I also see that it seems to pick the first unique(non-used) integer to begin a sequence. I'm stuck trying to implement this in Python.

I want to solve a facility location problem. I have 8128 distance values stored in an array. The code snippet below gets the first two relative distance arrays correct, but the 3rd repeats a value that has already been used before

```
distances = [[0 for col in range(2)] for row in range(128)] #this array contains line numbers that contain distances

#1st iteration works
startpoint = 0
count = 1
diff = 2

while startpoint < 8127:
    print distance[startpoint+diff]
    startpoint = startpoint+count
    count += 1
    diff += 2

#2nd iteration works
startpoint = 1
count = 2
diff = 3

while startpoint < 8127:
    print distance[startpoint+diff]
    startpoint = startpoint+count
    count += 1
    diff += 2

#3rd iteration repeats a value
startpoint = 2
count = 3
diff = 4

while startpoint < 8127:
    print distance[startpoint+diff]
    startpoint = startpoint+count
    count += 1
    diff += 2
```

Is there an example or an implementation of this algorithm out there?

Comment: Hi and Welcome! It appears as if you have recieved a school assignment, are asking us to solve a entire problem for you or simply find a library. Altho we love a good challenge and try to help out in the best ways possible.. Some questions require you to show some sort of effort in solving this yourself first. It would there for be helpful if you could post a snippet of code or proof of research in what solutions you've tried and what worked/didn't work and post a stack-trace, output or just a description of what whent wrong is sometimes enough.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what is being asked here; do you already have an algorithm and do not understand its inner workings or are you looking for an algorithm to solve a fixed problem?

Comment: @Codor: I'm looking for an algorithm to solve a facility location problem

Comment: Ok, please edit your question to provide more context.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "6. 17" with "7. 23" coming next?

Comment: Hint: note how each number is related to the next number (for the sequence 2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10, what is the pattern?). Here you are to look not per line, but look at the diagonal.

Comment: @justhalf: The vertical difference increases by 1 each time. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at diagonal difference?

Comment: @justhalf: Yes I see it now. I guess the problem now is implementing it in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance is maybe better represented as a function than as an array:

```
D(I, J) = I + J
```

where `I` and `J` are the (un-Pythonesuqe) one-based indices. (Do you realise that in your code, the distances are all zero?)

Also, you should probably be thinking in terms of your number of rows (128) rather than in terms of overall number of values (8128). The purpose of your three iterations is not clear to me. Shouldn't you have loops over rows and columns?

Anyway:

```
N = 128
n = 2

for i in range(N):
    m = n
    s = []
    for j in range(N - i):
        s.append(m)
        m += (j + 1) + (i + 1)

    print i + 1, s        
    n += i + 1
```

You can solve this in another way by noticing that every number occurs only once and follows a pattern:

```
 2   4   7  11
    /   /   /
   /   /   /
  /   /   /
 3   6  10
    /   /
   /   /
  /   /
 5   9
    / 
   / 
  / 
 8
```

Then you can create all lists up front and print them in a second loop:

```
n = 2
L = []

for i in range(N):
    L.append([])

    for LL in reversed(L):
        LL.append(n)
        n += 1

for i, LL in enumerate(L):
    print i + 1, LL
```

Comment: What do you mean by `D(I, J) = I + J`? Clearly the value of 4 in the 1st row and 2nd column is not equal to `1+2`. I think it should be `D[r,c] = 2 + (r+c)*(r+c+1)/2 + c`, where `r` and `c` are the row index and column index respectively (0-based).

Comment: `D` is what the OP calls distance. The difference between `a[i][j]` and `a[i][j + 1]` is `i + j + 2`. This is not the value 4, but the difference between 4 and the next value, 7.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood the notation, then.